# How can one eat non-certified kosher Israeli produce?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, eretz-yisrael, how-to, maaser-tithes, teruma

In Israel, there are many stores that are not certified kosher that sell produce grown in Israel. What is the procedure for taking teruma and maaser, and is there anything else a buyer would need to keep in mind?

Comment: Why ask about such stores and not the tree in one's backyard?

Comment: Aren't there clear instructions for tithing produce in just about every Siddur? What else are you seeking?

Comment: @DoubleAA instructions yes, I would argue about clear. Rather, it may say what to technically do, but gives 0 understanding of what you're doing.

Comment: @andrewmh20 Ok then that should suffice for the OP. If he's looking for something else, he should specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One separates the truma and ma'aser for oneself as explained by and Canadian [Council of Orthodox Rabbis - COR](http://www.cor.ca/view/61/produce_of_israel_a_primer.html) and the [OU Separating Terumah and Maaser](https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/separating-terumah-and-maaser/)

> 1) Place all of the produce in front of you.
>
> 2) Remove slightly more than 1% of the produce. For example, if there
>   are 100 oranges, one whole orange and a small part of a second orange
>   are separated.
>
> 3) A coin, which is valid currency in the country in which the
>   redemption is performed, is designated for redemption. At the time of
>   this writing, one nickel is sufficient3.
>
> 4) No blessing is recited because of the possibility (though remote)
>   that terumah and ma’ aser were separated in Israel.

Separate 10% of the remainder for ma'aser rishon.

> *Ma’ aser R.ishon*: 10% of the remaining produce is designated Ma’ aser
>   Rishon. This is normally given to the Levi, but may be eaten by
>   anyone. However, in practice, when purchasing produce in a store, the
>   halachah requires that the ma’ aser be designated, but it may then be
>   eaten by the owner of the produce, for the reason explained in
>   footnote 7 below.

Footnote 7 states:

> 7 There is a slight possibility that there is no obligation to tithe
>   the produce. One reason is that the local Rav may have already have
>   done so. Since this possibility is remote, the produce must be tithed.
>   However, there are sufficient grounds to apply the rule of hamotzi
>   mechavero olav horaya (the burden of proof lies with the extractor),
>   and the ma’ aser portion may be eaten after it is designated.

Note this:

> *Terumas Ma’ aser*: 10% of the Ma’ aser Rishon is separated and is
>   designated for the Kohen. As Terumah Gedolah, this may only be eaten
>   by a Kohen who is ritually pure, and it is therefore left uneaten
>   today. It., too, must be wrapped before it is discarded.

Separate 10% of the remainder for either Ma'aser Sheni (yers 1, 2, 4, 5) or Ma'aser Ani (years 3, 6) based on which year of the Shmittah cycle it is.

> A coin is designated for the redemption of Maaser Sheini. This coin must be worth at least a shoveh pruta. At the time of
>   writing, a nickel is sufficient.

One recites the appropriate text specifying which parts are trumah or ma'aser

> If one has difficulty reciting the full text or if it not available,
>   one may recite the following simplified version:
>
> "All separations of Terumah and Maaser and redemptions of Maaser
>   Sheini and Neta Revai shall be effected in accordance with the text of
>   the Chazon Ish."
>
> The separated portion is wrapped and discarded. The coin must be
>   disposed of so that no one shall accidentally find it and use it.

Comment: This answer is a bit too long, I think. Is there some way to summarize the most important points and just link to this very good article?

Comment: @DanF  I summarized where I could. How does this look?

Comment: However, AFAIR, some produce hashgachot in Israel and bechu"l specify that terumah, ma'aser, et c. have been pre-separated.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt The question as asked was what to do if there is no hashgacha for teruma and ma'aser. Of course if the hashgacha exists, then there is no need to do so again.

Comment: However the answer presupposes that the buyer is chayav regardless, unless I misread the language used.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt No, the chiyuv is because it was not under hashgacha. I added footnote 7 which points out that if truma and ma'aser had been separated there would have been no chiyuv.

Comment: orla is another problem with Israeli produce

Comment: @sabbahillel "Of course if the hashgacha exists, then there is no need to do so again." Not everyone agrees with this. Since none of us are Makpid on Taharot, it's possible the Gezera of Demai requires everyone to separate some parts again after purchase.