# How does one perform maaser rishon and maaser sheni and when is it required

Tags: maaser-tithes

I am aware that the first and second tithe must be performed on the fruits of Israel. What is the procedure for this and when is it required outside of the land of Israel?

Comment: https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/separating-terumah-and-maaser/

Comment: Make sure to read everything before acting. According to the OU at that link, dates exported from Israel to America are not considered "Sofek Orlah".

Comment: Actually, better than following @YaacovDeane's link is asking your rabbi what to do, since not everyone holds by everything in that link and you should get your rulings from your rabbi who knows the particulars of your situation.

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73196/759

Comment: http://www.crcweb.org/kosher_articles/Terumah%20and%20Ma'aser%20Separation%20(Apr%202013)-with%20pictures.pdf

Comment: The Kollel associated with DIN Online, who have semicha from the Chief Rabbinate of Israel also link to the OU site for the procedure.   http://dinonline.org/2012/08/19/procedure-for-separating-terumah-and-maaser/

Comment: http://keystone-k.org/diy-teruma-maaser-4-easy-steps/   The general idea here is that this is a common procedure that every practicing Jew should know. The vast majority of the Orthodox world in America holds this way.

Comment: I don't really see the point of continuing this discussion. If this question is reopend, we'll close it as a dupe. Move on.

Comment: Additional organizations following the same view: Aish HaTorah. http://www.aish.com/atr/Israeli_Produce.html    The Star-K.   http://www.star-k.org/articles/kosher-lists/1160/terumos-and-maasros/